# Access item in sequence that was skipped using LINQ's .Skip()

Tags: c#, linq

```
foreach(var item in items.Where(x => x.SomeCondition == true).Skip(1))
{
    item.OneThing = true;
    item.AnotherThing = true;
}
```

For the `item` that was skipped using `.Skip(1)`, I also need to set `.AnotherThing` to `true`. I can iterate everything without `.Skip(1)` and set `.AnotherThing` to `true`, then iterate everything with `.Skip(1)` and set `.OneThing` to `true`. Is there a more elegant way to do this, rather than looping through the collection twice?

Edit: What if there was a `.YetAnotherThing` property, which needed to be set on the item that was skipped using `.Skip(1)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it sounds like you don't want to use `Skip` in this case. Just use a local variable to remember whether this is the first iteration or not.

```
bool firstItem = true;
foreach(var item in items.Where(x => x.SomeCondition))
{
    item.AnotherThing = true;
    if (!firstItem)
    {
        item.OneThing = true;
    }
    firstItem = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon, seems like I'm "over-LINQing" things :) What happens when you need to set a property on the item that was skipped using `.Skip(1)`? Would I need to isolate it in a variable first and then edit it? (I've edited the question, but can ask in a new thread if necessary)

Comment: In that case, you still need to get the first record, so you can either do it in 1 query (as per this answer), or you can do it in 2 queries, by not using `Skip(1)` and instead just using  `Take(1)`. In order to update an entity you need to get it from the store - skipping it explicitly does NOT get it from the store.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Skip(1)` in your `foreach` loop then. You can also do a `Select` to get the index as the second parameter.

```
foreach (var item in items.Where(x => x.SomeCondition)
                          .Select((x, i) => new { item = x, index = i })
{
    // If you have a lot to do:
    if (item.index != 0)
    {
        item.item.YetAnotherThing = 15;
        item.item.OneThing = true;
    }

    // If you have a simple boolean
    item.item.OneThing = item.index != 0;

    // Something that will always happen.
    item.item.AnotherThing = true;
}
```

Granted, in actual code, please pick better variable names than what would create `item.item`.

Comment: FWIW, I would do it the way that Jon has it (no surprise). However, this is another alternative that is good to keep in your back pocket. There are those rare cases when this comes in handy.

Comment: Thanks @krillgar. What happens if there was a 3rd property which needed to be set on the `.Skip(1)` item? (see my edit)

Comment: @globetrotter Updated.

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
var newItems = items.Where(x => x.SomeCondition == true).ToList();
if(newItems.Count != 0)
{
    newItems.ForEach(i => i.AnotherThing = true);
    newItems.FirstOrDefault().OneThing = true;
}
```

Comment: The downside to this is that you're going to iterate/evaluate over your collection twice.

Comment: you are right. And also I have noticed `ForEach` is not supported in `IEnumerable` will update my answer